# I want to append |||||| at the end of everyline. If there is a delimiter already then it should be a total of 6 at the eol

Tags: notepad++

Eg : this| is| a |basket of appples.
        This |is| a basket of mangoes|||
...

All must be replaced with |||||| at the end of line

What should be the regexp.

Comment: What did you already try? Where did you run into problems when you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### All lines should end with `||||||`

You need to do this in two passes.

**Pass 1**:

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(.*?)$`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1||||||`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

**Pass 2**:

- Set "Find what" to `(.*?)[\|]+$`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1||||||`
- Click "Replace All"

**Before**:

```
this| is| a |basket of appples. This |is| a basket of mangoes
this| is| a |basket of appples. This |is| a basket of mangoes|||
```

**After**:

```
this| is| a |basket of appples. This |is| a basket of mangoes||||||
this| is| a |basket of appples. This |is| a basket of mangoes||||||
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)